# How do I stop all workers in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, threadpool

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor for multiple processes in my project, I have a stop button in my design, when I click the button, I want to stop the processes. My work is to check whether the urls exist. Please help I don't know how to stop it.

Here is my code:

```py
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from concurrent import futures
import concurrent.futures       

list = [] # There are various URLs in the list. They are pulled from the txt document.
oKlist [] # successful urls

def wControl(urls):
    try:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
        sUrl = urls
        r = requests.get(sUrl, headers=headers,verify=False, timeout=20)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return sUrl
        
        

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    result = executor.map(wControl,list)
    for i in result:
        if i != None:
            oKlist.append(i)
```

Comment: Does the [```Executor.shutdown()```](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html#executor-objects) method not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: You will need to start by fixing your syntax errors. Then you'll notice that all the threads terminate naturally as the wControl() function doesn't have any kind of looping that you need to break out of. It will either return the value referenced by sUrl or None

Comment: Executor.shutdown() unfortunately didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then as @Homer512 stated, you could try using [`Executor.shutdown()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown). However, as you will notice, this might still hang for a bit as opposed to shutting down workers instantly, which seems to be what you want to do.

I suggest you instead use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) and leverage their [`Pool.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) functionality, which will "stop the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work":

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from time import sleep

# Specify the amount of workers you want to use
with Pool(2) as pool:
    # Add tasks to pool to run
    for i in range(100):
        print(f"Adding task {i}")
        pool.apply_async(sleep, [30])
    print("Executing...")

    # After 3 seconds, we will kill all the tasks instantly
    sleep(3)
    print("Terminating...")
    pool.terminate()
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: Why not? What happened @Akif

Comment: Where is my mistake?  with Pool(2) as pool:
    for i in list:
        print(f"Adding task {i}")
        pool.apply_async(wControl, [i])
    print("Executing...")


    sleep(3)
    print("Terminating...")
    pool.terminate()
    print("Done!")

Comment: If you need more help implementing the answer in your own code, then make a new question. If my question solves your problem, though, then mark it with the check mark on the left.